# How to add NULL item into drop down?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have following properties in my model class

```
public Gender? Gender { get; set; }

[ForeignKey(nameof(Nationality))]
public int? NationalityId { get; set; }

public Nationality Nationality { get; set; }
```

Pay attention that `NationalityId` should be nullable. This my intention, so data type of it I am declaring as `int?`.

I am adding controller for the model by scaffolding. So I have both actions and views generated by Visual Studio.

When I run the application and open the drop down, on `NationalityId` property, I am getting list of Nationality records and without a NULL value in the list. So a user cannot set this property null. However, the property `Gender`, whose data type is enum, has both values of the enum and an option NULL (empty item), which lets a user to set the property null.

**How to force drop down of property `NationalityId` work the same as the drop down of property `Gender`?**

Here are screenshots

`Gender` property drop down

[image]

`NationalityId` property drop down

[image]

---

Additional information

Here is mark up generated by Studio

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NationalityId, "NationalityId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("NationalityId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NationalityId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I have Sql database.

Comment: how are you binding this dropdown? hardcoding or getting from the database? why can't you have it if the user doesn't select any item from the dropdown and just store the default value `null` for `nationalityid`?

Comment: Could you please share your `front-end` code snippet for better clarity and reproduce the issue.

Comment: II think that you'll need to bind so that when the value is NULL you use a space

Comment: @vivek nuna, first of all, when there are Nationality records the drop down is automatically selecting the firts item. Secondly, I want to leave an option to set the property null.

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper you need to add item for `null` in you dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have used following overload of extension methods to generate drop-down

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList
    (
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
    string optionLabel,
    object htmlAttributes
    )
{
    ...
}
```

passing `string.Empty` to 3rd parameter named `optionLabel`. Then the markup would be

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NationalityId, "NationalityId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("NationalityId", null, string.Empty, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NationalityId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

This [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/qpAe45xTEfQ?t=474) explains how to use this method.